# Selected Value of Select2

Tags: php, jquery-select2

I have an option where I can select an option from a select2 dropdown and when I click save it saves to the database and also display as an editable dropdown as a list below where I could update it if required. How can I show the already selected value of this editable dropdown?

This is what I tried. So within this td tag is the 2nd select2 which should show the selected value from above select2 dropdown. The select2 dropdown option is called via an api function.

```
       $display .= '<td>';

       $display .= "<span class='printonly'>" . htmlentities($cell) . "</span>

      <select class='select2' name='select2' placeholder = 'SELECT a $column' onchange='updateData(this)'>";

      $display .= "<option value='' selected disabled></option>";

     // $display .= "<option value = $('.select2').find(':selected')> </option>";
      $display .= "</select>";
      $display .= '</td>';
```

Comment: You're right that the `selected` attribute should be in the option you want to show.

Comment: But it doesn't work or show the selected value on the editable dropdown @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Well, currently the code in your question makes little sense. It seems to start with HTML and then transition into PHP without a `<?php`. Then it builds on a non-existing `$display` variable and does nothing with it. You have a `selected`, but in a completely empty option. Sorry, but unless you provide some code that makes a little bit more sense, I can't help you.

Comment: Sorry. I have updated the code @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't really help much. I can't decide whether you have a "selected" value in PHP, which you want to put in a "selected" option in PHP, or whether this is something that should be done in the browser with Javascript/Jquery. So, I guess my question is: Where is the value you want to show in the selected option?